# create a case statement in Controller to open up the correct View

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a page (view) called "test." It has 3 links with a variable"?vars='some_number'"

How can I pass this number to the controller and based on the number, open up the view that it corresponds to?

I was thinking a case statement in the view, but I am not sure how to get the variable to the controller.

```
case vars == 1: return("view1");
case vars == 2: return("view2");
case vars == 3: return("view3");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do so, but you can have your action like this (assuming you're in ASP.net MVC)

```
public ActionResult Test(int id){
 switch(id){
  case 1:
    return View("view1");
  case 2:
    return View("view2");
  case 3:
    return View("view3");

  }

}
```

and the link to this will be YourController/Test/1 or something like this

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (A bit puzzled on your approach):

```
public class HomeController
{
     public void Index(int vars) 
     {
          return this.View(string.Format("view{0}", vars));
     }
}
```

Perhaps that would work for you.

To clarify the links in this scenario would be: /Home/Index?vars=2